# Identify overlap percent of IDs between 2 dates in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table of names with two different dates. I want to know the count of names that are occurring between the two dates and the overlap percentage.

This is the output format that is desired. I am not looking for dates in between. I am looking for records that are in July 05 and also in August 10. Overlap percentage for each id would be - count of records in July 5 and also August 10/count of records on July 5.(Actual table has dates in date datatype).

Overlap % will always be less than or equal to 100 since count of records existing on July 5 as well as August 10 will always be <=count of records on July 5.

| id | Count on July 05 | Count of IDs from July 05 included in August 10 | % overlap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC |  |  |  |
| BCD |  |  |  |
| CDE |  |  |  |
| DEF |  |  |  |
| EFG |  |  |  |

Rough version of the input table

| id | type | Group | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Mobile | 1 | July 5 |
| BCD | Mobile | 1 | July 5 |
| ABC | Desktop | 1 | August 10 |
| CDE | Mobile | 2 | July 5 |
| BCD | Mobile | 2 | August 10 |

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! It will be helpful if you include some sample data.

Comment: No please don't write it in the comment section, kindly [edit] your question and add it there.

Comment: @the_coding_cat. Added. Appreciate any help

Comment: Is your `date` column really formatted like that? Is that a varchar? You'll have a hard time comparing and fetching data in that case, date should have a date datatype.

Comment: Please be more precise about what you want to do. Do you want to check if the date is one of two dates (this is the column name in your expected outcome) or do you want to check if the date is between two dates (this is your text above the outcome)? So if there is an entry like July 20, should this entry be considered or not when checking July 5 and August 10?

Comment: "Count of IDs from July 05 included in August 10", "%overlap" vs "count of names that are occurring between the two dates and the overlap percentage".... Please be more precise.

What would the results be from the correct query for the example you provided?

Comment: @JonasMetzler. I am not looking for dates in between. I am looking for records that are in July 05 and also in August 10. Overlap percentage for each id would be - count of records in July 5 and also August 10/count of records on July 5

Comment: Just to be sure that we understand you correctly, for ABC id it will be (1+2)/1

Comment: @Ahmed, I have simplified the input table a bit. So for ABC, it will be 1/1(1 record on July 5 that is also in August 10/ 1 record on July 5).
Percentage will always be less than or equal to 100 since count of records existing on July 5 as well as August 10 will always be <=count of records on July 5.

Comment: And what about the `type` field, is it not important? ABC July 5 its (mobile) and August 10 its (desktop)

Comment: @Ahmed, it would be great if you could provide me the percentage of records based on id and type as well. But my primary request is to get only the count of overlapping ids and not other columns

Comment: Are you using all thos DB systems at the same time???? That sounds awesome. You should tag properly with the exact DB you use, not with all the ones you know

Comment: And you should never, never, never store dates as strings in that way

Comment: @nacho. Fair enough. The dates are actually in date format in the actual table, but my question is more geared towards figuring out the logic here. Any help toward that is appreciated.

Comment: Tag only the database you are using. Please show the query you tried and what it returns vs what you expected

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen. I was only able to figure out counts as an individual query. My output format given above is not in the direction of what I am trying right now, so i wanted to keep the thought process clean here. Any help towards figuring the logic out is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your comments, the overlap will be the minimum count value of the two dates, i.e. for ABC if we have 6 in July and 2 in August the overlap will be 2, and if we have 3 in July and 5 in August the overlap will be 3.

If that is the case then you may use the following query tested on `MS SQL Server 2019`:

```
SELECT  t.id, t.[Count on July 05],
CASE
WHEN t.[Count on July 05]<= t.[Count of August 10] THEN t.[Count on July 05]
WHEN t.[Count on July 05]> t.[Count of August 10] THEN t.[Count of August 10]
END AS [Count of IDs from July 05 included in August 10],
CASE
WHEN t.[Count on July 05]<= t.[Count of August 10] THEN CAST(t.[Count on July 05]*1.00/t.[Count on July 05] * 100 AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
WHEN t.[Count on July 05]> t.[Count of August 10] THEN CAST(t.[Count of August 10]*1.00/t.[Count on July 05] * 100 AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
END AS [% overlap]
FROM(
SELECT id, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [tdate] IN ('July 5') THEN 1 END) as [Count on July 05],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [tdate] IN ('August 10')  THEN 1 END) as [Count of August 10]
FROM [Tbl]
GROUP BY id) t
```

I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: If I misunderstood you, provide a more detailed example to help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will test this tomorrow morning and update here